# Brand wise searching in product orderer report

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.4

1. I am trying to extend product order
   report and add one Attribute of
   product brand and put into
   **grid.phtml.**
2. when i select brand and click on
   **refresh** button.
3. report will not display brand wise
   searching what can i do?

**product order report image link**
Visit 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/productorder.jpg/

**grid.phtm Code**

```
<?php 
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
->setCodeFilter('brand')
->getFirstItem();
$attributeOptions = $attributeInfo->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
                            ?>
                    </div>

                    --><div class="f-left">
                    <?php echo $this->__('Brand') ?>:
                    <select name="brand" id="brand" style="width:6em;">
                    <?php foreach ($attributeOptions as $_value=>$_label): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $_value ?>" <?php if($this->getFilter('brand')==$_value): ?> selected<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_label['label'] ?></option>
                       <?php //error_log("Lable".print_r($_label,TRUE));?>
                    <?php endforeach;  ?>
                    </select>

                </div>
```